# Changing 2d array values in Python

Tags: python

I have a the shape of an array like so, called arry

```
[[1 2 3]
[4 3 1]
[2 2 3]]
```

and I want to replace those values with letters

```
dict = {1:'x',2:'y',3:'x',4:'y'}
for x in xrange (3):
    for y in xrange (3):
        a = dict[arry[y][x]]
        arry[y][x].fill(a)
```

However I get the error invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'n'
Why is this?
I've also tried

```
arry[y][x] = dict[arry[y][x]]
```

Comment: How is arry declared?

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine on my machine :

```
arry = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1], [2, 2, 3]]

dict = {1:'x',2:'y',3:'x',4:'y'}
for x in xrange (3):
    for y in xrange (3):
        arry[y][x] = dict[arry[y][x]]
print arry
```

I guess you have wrongly initialized the arry variable , the values in list are seprated by comma.

Comment: arry needs to be input as I have said, is there way to input these commas

Comment: ok give me a sample input , how would you like to input the array ? Using space separated elements or some other way ? plz provide input ?

Comment: The input is what I've said before, not sure why there aren't commas in it

Comment: I'm using a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> array=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1], [2, 2, 3]]
>>> ref_dict = {1:'x',2:'y',3:'x',4:'y'}
>>> print [map(lambda x:ref_dict[x], l) for l in array]
[['x', 'y', 'x'], ['y', 'x', 'x'], ['y', 'y', 'x']]
```

You should not declare `dict` as your dictionary name as you will override the behaviour of dict class.

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> d
{}
>>> dict = {1:2, 3:4}
>>> dict
{1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> d_new = dict()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```